# iPhone Scroll images horizontally like in AppStore

Tags: iphone, html, css, uiwebview

I was wondering if it's possible to create a HTML div container with some CSS magic that shows a horizontal scrollbar like the one with the screenshots on the iTunes preview on the web. I want this to work in Safari on the iPhone.

e.g. http://itunes.apple.com/app/super-monkey-ball/id281966695?mt=8

I would like to use that to display thumbnails in an UIWebView on iPhone. I experimented with the overflow css property but didn't get it to work.

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have time to test it right now, but I think something along the lines of the following should work:

```
ul#container
{
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: scroll;
width: 500px; /* or whatever */
height: 200px; /* or whatever */
white-space: nowrap;
}

ul#container li
{
display: inline-block;
width: 100px; /* or whatever */
height: 200px; /* or whatever */
}


<ul id="container">
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item Two</li>
  <li>Item three</li>
  <li>...<!-- you get the point --></li>
</ul>
```

You might need to use `float: left;` on the `li` elements, but I'm not sure. And it maybe depends on the browser you, or your users, will be using.

I'll check this out when I get home, but for now I offer you a demo at: http://jsbin.com/atuvo

Comment: Thanks for your answer! On Firefox, Safari on Mac it works fine, but if I open the demo on the iPhone, no scrollbar is shown. You only see Item 1 to Item 5.

Comment: @schaechtele, sorry it's taken so long to respond, but the only way I can find for an iPhone to allow for scrolling within an element is to drag with two fingers...which is insane, and still doesn't show scroll bars (that's using mobile safari, Opera for iPhone doesn't even allow for `whitespace: nowrap`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
We did a nice component that works with jQuery. It's easy to use.

http://api.mutado.com/mobile/mtdtouch/js/

There's is also a demo that works on iPhone and iPad if you want to try it.

Cheers,
Lorenzo

Answer (score 0):

iScroll is pretty awesome too, it does nice horizontal momentum scrolling: http://cubiq.org/iscroll

Answer (score 0):

You can take it here http://appradar.ru/

```
<script src="http://appradar.ru/wp-content/themes/appradar/js/jquery.horizontal.scroll.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var w = 0, h = 0;
            $('#slider div').each(function(i, index){
                w += $(this).outerWidth(); 
                h = $(this).outerHeight() > h ? $(this).outerHeight() : h;
            });
            $('#slider').width(w).height(h);
            $('#slider-outer').height(h + 8).horizontalScroll();            
        });
    </script>
```