# Swipe a Table Row/Cell Left and Right

Tags: jquery, ios, html, jquery-mobile

Attempting to have data in a table row that has multiple columns within the row only display one column in the view at a time, but moves independently from the other rows above and below it without scrolling bars.  I am attempting to use swiping in a mobile platform, either HTML5, jQuery, iOS, or jQMobile; whichever is more capable.

A good example of what I'm attempting to do is how the Apple App Store looks on a mobile device...the table also still is capable of moving up and down like a normal table.

Thank you all for this community.
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the following link. I think this exactly what you are looking for am I right? This isn't a complete app store, but it is an example of horizontal table scrolling that you can use in your project. The rest will be pretty easy. I would suggest using some CSS to make it pretty.

[Link to Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728715/iphone-scroll-images-horizontally-like-in-appstore)

Comment: Riley - Sorry for the delay after careful review of your recommendation I believe I found the solution which should work: http://api.mutado.com/mobile/mtdtouch/js/ui.scroll.html Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you out.